# InputMismatchException in Java replacing while loop

Tags: java, exception

In my task I need to put InputMismatchException when user tries to enter some values. User get some numbers from 1 to some number (simptoms.lenght).

```
int number=0;
            do{
                System.out.printf("Choose %d simptoms: \n", number+1);
                for(int j=0; j< simptomi.length;j++){
                    System.out.printf("%d. %s %s\n", j + 1, simptoms[j].getName(), 
simptoms[j].getValue());

            }
            System.out.print("Choose: ");

            while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Please enter number!");
                scanner.next();
            }
            
            
            number=scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            if(number<0 || number> simptoms.length){
                System.out.println("Error, choose again");

            }

        }while(number<0  || number> simptoms.length);
```

After this code I tried to do this:
instead of while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) I tried with try and I get this message:

Declaration, final or effectively final variable expected.

Is this the right way of replacing while loop or I should try to add something else.
I'm thinking about boolean = false and somehow try with that but I don't understand how to implement it properly.

I tried this:

```
  try{
     number=scanner.nextInt();
     scanner.nextLine();
     }

     catch (InputMismatchException ex){
     System.out.println("Please, enter number!");
            }
```

Comment: Would you please paste the code you tried to replace the while-loop with so that we could see it?

Comment: Problem is now it will go exception but wont wait for right input

Comment: ``hasNextInt()`` only tells you that the input isn't an int. There could be several alphabetical characters (or other non-digits) in the buffer. And an int will never be found, no matter what the person enters at this point.

Comment: I know how to check it with wile loop but how to implement it in try()

Comment: The try/catch still needs to be within a while-loop. Do the nextInt() call within the try. If that works, break out of the loop. If you end up in the catch, then print something like "Enter a number:" then allow the while-loop to continue.

Comment: try{
                number=scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
            }

Comment: I tried with this but it gets me to enter a new number, but it also gets me to enter e.g. 5th simptom even If i have only 3 simptoms. If I enter 0 program crashes

Comment: Randomly using nextLine() is a bad idea.

Comment: After every int input I do that. How to check if number isn't correct in try

Comment: Just use nextInt(). Or better yet, use a BufferedReader and parse it yourself. I *never* use Scanner.

Comment: I have to use it. I have 2 problems now.

Comment: First: If I enter 4 I'll get message choose 5 simptoms(number) is now 4 and If I enter 0 program crashes

Answer (score 0):

Try it out! hope it helps!

```
try {
    do {
        number = scanner.nextInt();

        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(number)) {
            if (number > simptoms.length) {
                System.out.println("Error, choose again");
                System.out.println("Please enter number!");
            }
        }
    } while (number != -1);
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Enter number");
}
```

Comment: Hmm helps but I need to check (!scanner.hasNextInt())

Comment: Use (scanner.hasNext()) in do-while loop......!


try {
   do {
    number = scanner.nextInt();

    if (!Character.isAlphabetic(number)) {
     if (number > simptoms.length) {
      System.out.println("Error, choose again");
      System.out.println("Please enter number!");
     }
    }
   } while (scanner.hasNext());
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
   System.out.println("Enter number");
  }